# Невозможно найти указанный файл чертежа.

Tags: windows, autocad

У меня в программе AutoCAD 2014 сообщение об ошибке: *«Невозможно найти указанный файл чертежа. Убедитесь, что файл существует». при двойном щелчке мышью файла DWG для его открытия в AutoCAD*[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чего начать по устранению ошибки?

Comment: *С чего начать по устранению ошибки?* C проверки ассоциации расширения в реестре. Или по-простому - восстановление ассоциации репайром или вообще установкой поверх, пусть и той же самой версии. Наиболее частая причина (если не считать реального повреждения ключа) - потерянные обрамляющие кавычки.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала нужно задать себе простой вопрос и ответить на него:

> Эта проблема возникает при открытии какого-то одного файла или любых
>   файлов автокада?

Если у вас не открывается ни один файл -- есть какая-то глобальная проблема, которая возможно действительно потребует переустановки из-за поломки софта.

Если у вас не открывается какой-то один конкретный файл -- нужно внимательно изучить имя файла на наличие специальных символов.

Вполне возможно, что файл был получен по почте/из интернета/скопирован с другой файловой системы, где иные разрешённые наборы символов. Коллеги-шутники также не исключены, хотя это больше студенческие шуточки.

Для начала попробуйте проблемный файл переложить с именем 123.dwg в папку в которой у вас гарантированно открываются другие файлы (например, папка "Мои чертежи"). Если проблема исчезнет при переименовании -- значит, попробуйте заменять подозрительные символы в имени файла.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала сами проверьте - а AutoCAD'овский ли файл Вы пытаетесь восстановить. Для этого откройте файл в Блокноте или любом другом простом текстовом редакторе и посмотрите на символы, с которых начинается содержание файла. Если первыми 6 символами не являются AC10(и тут две цифры), можете даже не пытаться - это не файл AutoCAD.
Соответствие первоначальных символов и версий AutoCAD:
*AC1014 - AutoCAD R14
AC1015 - AutoCAD 2000, 2000i, 2002
AC1018 - AutoCAD 2004, 2005, 2006
AC1021 - AutoCAD 2007, 2008, 2009
AC1024 - AutoCAD 2010, 2011*
Задайте вопрос на [dwgru](http://forum.dwg.ru/) и на [autodesk](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/ru/support/autocad/)

Вот еще вариант решения: Выполните одно из следующих действий.
-Удалите символы косой черты («/» или «\») из имени пути к папке с файлом чертежа и самой папки.
-Отредактируйте ключ /p в поле ярлыка Цель для AutoCAD (например, щелкните правой кнопкой мыши > «Свойства» > «Ярлык»), чтобы имя профиля отображалось кавычках (например, /p "мой профиль.arg").
-Измените поле ярлыка Цель для AutoCAD и убедитесь, что указан допустимый файл DWG (если он необходим), либо удалите его. Для использования в AutoCAD Map 3D и в параметрах входа в промышленную модель файл необходимо указать (см. раздел Подключение к отраслевой модели из командной строки).Восстановите сопоставление типов файлов чертежа (см. раздел Двойной щелчок на файле DWG не запускает AutoCAD) источник **autodesk**
Так же пробуйте [рекавери](https://onlinefilerepair.com/ru/autocad-repair-online.html) dwg исправить. Ну и само собой отписывайтесь о своих действиях.

Comment: Этот ответ как-то связан с конкретной ошибкой из вопроса?

Comment: Ошибка связана с файлом чертежа. Пункты решения должны помочь выявить причину или их часть.

Comment: Если файл повреждён, то, вероятно, должна показываться другая ошибка, а не о несуществовании файла?